# NativeScript Angular - Server Sent Events

Tags: nativescript, server-sent-events, nativescript-angular

What can I use to deal with Server Sent Events in NS+Angular? EventSource does not seem to work for me. The code and error is as follows:

```
const source = new EventSource( URL, Headers );
source.addEventListener('message', (message) => {
  console.log( message );
});
```

Error:

> EventSource is not defined.

I am sure that my URL and Headers are valid.

I have also tried using the Nativescript-sse plugin, but the documentation for that plugin is not good. Here is the code in the documentation:

```
import { SSE } from 'nativescript-sse';

let sse = new SSE("ServerAPI", {headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'});
sse.events.on('onConnect', (data) => {
    console.log(data.object.connected);
});
sse.events.on('onMessage', (data) => {
    this.list.push(JSON.parse(data.object.message.data))
});
sse.events.on('onError', (data) => {
    console.log(data.object.error);
});
see.close();
```

Error:

> I cannot even access sse.events. The "events" property does not seem to exist.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: It suppose to be `
let sse = new SSE("YourServerAPI", { headerKey: headerValue});`. What does logging `sse` shows you?

Comment: @Manoj Yes I did change that into an actual string, I will edit it now. 

If I include headers, there is an error => Error: Cannot Convert object to Ljava/lang/Object; at index 1

If I do not include headers, it shows this:

JS: {
JS:   "_url": {},
JS:   "events": {
JS:     "_observers": {},
JS:     "_map": {}
JS:   },
JS:   "_sseHandler": {},
JS:   "_headers": {},
JS:   "_es": {}
JS: }

Comment: The addEventListener for SSE doesn't have a callback as well. How am I supposed to receive the stream data?

Comment: You have `events` object which actually triggers events, `addEventListener` is not meant to be used on SSE instance.

Comment: Right but in the actual code I cannot access "events" property. Only connect(), close(), addEventListener() and removeEventListener(). That is the plugin's documentation that you see in my post.